# Android css3 gradient text question

Tags: android, text, css, gradient

How can i make gradient text with css3 working in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the webkit background-clip: text; setting:

For more examples see http://www.css3.info/webkit-introduces-background-cliptext/

Answer (score 0):

I found this on google. It overlays a span over your text, so your background needs to be the same color as your gradient, but it should work on all browsers.

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect

Another option, which does mask the text thus you can put it in any background, is to use `-webkit-gradient:` and `-webkit-mask-image:`, which will work in android because it uses a webkit rendering engine, but not on Firefox or IE. Firefox has an alternative `-moz-linear-gradient:`, but I dont know how well can you mask it to text though, and on IE, I have no clue... I'm pretty sure it isn't supported yet. Heres a video tutorial and sample code on how to use it:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-pure-css-text-gradients/

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried the secont one and here is how it looks like in android: http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/5014/androidw.png . In iphone everything works well, but I want to do this to work with android without any pngs, only with css3 :(

Comment: The problem seems to be `-webkit-mask-image` :/ What version of Android are you using? Maybe support for it will come later on. :/ Sorry, I cant think of any other way of doing it other than using PNGs... Good luck.

Comment: I'm using emulator, because I'm going to take part in contest about mobile web app.